# Can you use a dataframe index as a conditional

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am trying to iterate through a dataframe and use the index as a conditional to determine what value gets placed in the responding cell. The columns are being added to my dataframe but the conditional is working. I've spent the past few days trying to figure out why, but can't.

Here's my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
  

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
 
df1.index =['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4']

multipliers = range(1, 55, 1)
counter = 0
for i in multipliers:
    counter += 1

    print(i)
    for j, row in df1.iterrows():
        print(counter)
        
        print(j)
        if j == 'Item 1':
            df1[f'period_{i}'] = 10
                  
        else:
            df1[f'period_{i}'] = 100
df1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for

check out this [cheat sheet](https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) or the source documentation for indexing and selecting data.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

df1.index = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]

multipliers = range(1, 55, 1)
counter = 0
for i in multipliers:
    counter += 1

mask = df1.index == "Item 1"
df1.loc[mask, f"period_{i}"] = 10
df1[~mask] = 100
```

a little more explanation.

`mask = df1.index == "Item 1"`

creates an `ndarray[bool]`

and in this case

`[True False False False]`

Where a the condition is `True` The value is set

the `~` bitwise operator will invert the array and the mask becomes

`[False True True True]`

Comment: thanks Jason for your timely response. will try this solution you offered. quick questions for you. I am building my python skills. in many cases i am trying to create python code that replicates excel spreadsheets i've used in the past. many of my spreadsheets would use data from [0, 7] in a calculation in [1, 3]. does python calculate cells down column by column? or across row by row? where can i find information that explains this?

Comment: ‘python’ does not allow for ‘column’ computations. 

Pandas which is built on top of numpy does. More specifically N dimensional Arrays.  Pandas data is represented as a table of NDArrays.  Each column is an array of data. The variables on the left of the dataframe are the index and variables on the top are your columns.  Sometimes refered to as axis 0 or axis 1